# saving and loading list values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one of the columns contains a list of values:

example:
`type(df['col_list'].values[0])` = `list`

I saved this dataframe as csv file (`df.to_csv('my_file.csv')`)

When I load the dataframe (`df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')`)
the column which contains list of values change to `string` type:
`type(df['col_list'].values[0])` = `str`

When converting to list (`list(df['col_list'].values[0]`) I'm getting list of characters instead of list of values.

How can I save/load dataframe which one of it's columns contains list of values ?

Comment: I'm able to save `list` column as it is in `csv`. My pandas version: `'1.2.3'`. What version are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the table being saved as CSV and serializing the values of the list. The csv format is unable to save the list object as it is. Try saving in another format `df.to_pickle('test.df')`. You can then read this back into a dataframe with [read_pickle](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html)

Read more on saving to pickle [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html)

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON` or `HDF` file format instead of CSV. CSV file format is really inconvenient for storing a list or a collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think Anurag's suggestion is very good. But just in case you want to keep things the way it is, this will do the job

```
import json
df['col_list'] = df['col_list'].apply(json.loads)
```

This would work better if you had converted `col_list` into JSON text before `pd.to_csv` by

```
df['col_list'] = df['col_list'].apply(json.dumps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider saving it as an excel file, if that's an option.

```
df.to_excel('my_file.xlsx',index=False)
```